# Inserting into a std::map and manipulating the obtained iterator to the inserted element

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I know that, if I insert a value into a `std::map` I can obtain an iterator referring to the inserted element (or the element which was previously there) by checking inserts return value like so:

```
std::map<int, char> m;
auto ret = m.insert(std::make_pair(1, 'A'));
if (ret.second)
    std::cout << "it worked" << std::endl;
// ... now iterations over the map starting at ret.first
```

However, I was wondering whether it is legal to manipulate the obtained iterator afterwards, e.g. assign the desired value in the case of a failure.

```
std::map<int, char> m;
auto ret = m.insert(std::make_pair(1, 'A'));
if (!ret.second)
    ret.first->second = 'A'; // assign the value in case it went wrong
```

I noticed that this seems to work, but I am not sure whether this is the desired behaviour since everything I found in case of an failed insertion was to use the `operator[]` instead. However this would not be a solution for me, because I need the iterator returned by `insert` afterwards and I can't use `insert` and the `operator[]` because of performance reasons.

***Long story short:*** Is it valid to manipulate the data referenced by an iterator returned from `std::map`s `insert()`?

Comment: You could also use `std::map::count` first, instead of trying to insert.

Comment: @Jonas But `std::map::count` also has a complexity of O(log(N)) so it would be as bad as doing `m[1] = 'A'` in case of a failed insertion, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***Long story short:*** Is is valid to manipulate the data referenced by an iterator returned from `std::map`s `insert()`?

Yes, this is just fine.  You cannot modify the key as that is `const` but you can modify the value the key is mapped to as much as you want.